# What is the operator "" in C++?

Tags: c++, operators, language-design

I fell on [this page](http://www.akiwi.co.uk/programming.html) where the author talks about the *standardisation of the operator ""*:

> The decision of the C++ standards committee to **standardise `operator ""`**
>   was [...]

What is he/she talking about? I can't find any information about this, and I don't understand what it could imply (overload for constant strings? Or something more conceptual, that doesn't affect the final use of the language?)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Those are [user-defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal). They allow you to create stuff like `std::string`, `std::chrono::durations` or any user defined type (you can make your own literals) in place:

```
auto str = "Hello"s; // str is std::string("Hello")
auto sec = 5s;       // sec is 5 std::chrono::seconds
```

A list of the literal-operators provided by the standard library and their documentation can be found at the bottom of the documentation page I linked.

Answer (score 3):

It's the [user-defined literal operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn919277.aspx) which will allow the introduction of new literal syntax based on existing literals.

For more information, show [this reference link](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/user-defined-literals-part-i/).

Comment: @BaummitAugen I think `36.0_mi` is a user defined literal, isn't it?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: The answer's examples were `128u`, `128l`, `128.0f`, and `0xBAD`.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Yeah, the examples I was talking about were removed in the meantime.